# To solve a polynomial equation defined by a determinant.

Tags: linear-algebra

Solve the equation.

Det$
\begin{bmatrix}
    1       & x & x^2 & \dots & x^n \\
    1       & a_1 & a_1^2 & \dots & a_1^n \\
    \vdots   & \vdots  & \vdots  & \vdots \\
     1  &  a_n  & a_n^2 & \ldots & a_n^n
\end{bmatrix}
 =0$

I am trying to work out an exercise on determinants but it seems I am stuck at the very beginning. Most of the problems are of this nature. It seems I am missing a crucial tool to crack these problems. A useful hint will come a long way.

All I can think of is using the elementary matrix operations. But that seems to be getting me nowhere.

Comment: This is called a Vandermonde determinant and it factors easily. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this determinant (call it $D(x)$) will be at most a $n^{\text{th}}$ degree polynomial in $x$, therefore let us try to get its roots. When $x=a_1$, then the first two rows are same hence the determinant is $0$. This means this polynomial should have $x-a_1$ as a factor. Likewise we can say $x-a_i$ is a factor of this polynomial for all $1 \leq i \leq n$. This means
$$D(x)=A(x-a_1)(x-a_2)(x-a_3)\dotsb (x-a_n).$$
Now see if you can get the constant $A$ as well.